# Looping redirect in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this simple .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mydom.net [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) www.mydom.net/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]
```

Works fine, except entering with query string `mydom.net/?view=xyz`; it then goes into a redirect loop:

```
https://mydom.net/var/www/domdir/www.mydom.net/var/www/domdir/www.mydom.net/var/www/domdir/...
```

but more strange is why is it inserting the `DocumentRoot=/var/www/domdir` in the first place?

What's wrong?

---

Added explanation for the record: this was intended to force all requests to mydom.net to be `https://www.mydom.net` with or without query string.

Comment: Nope, that's the whole .htaccess. No httpd.conf, using Ubuntu, and the apache2.conf is vanilla + AllowOverride in /var/www.

Comment: Is `DocumentRoot` being declared somewhere?

Comment: Yes, of course in mydom.net.conf...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why a query string would make a difference sounds like a non-related browser cashing issue from your 301 permanent redirect.
Let's say they entered `http://mydom.net/?view=xyz`
The first rule doesn't begin with http or https so it treats your rewrite like a directory. You'd be rewritten to `http://mydom.net/www.mydom.net` then, because your first rule has no `L` flag your 2nd rule applies, so you get rewritten to: `https://mydom.net/www.mydom.net` the .htaccess file is read from the top since the URL changed. no `www.` detected, so you get rewritten to `http://mydom.net/var/www/domdir/www.mydom.net/` etc.

I believe a fix would be something close to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.mydom.net [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.mydom.net/%1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer and explanation, that works! I'm just getting extra // before the ?view query; will figure it out and comment later.

Comment: Edited try that and it should take care of the // problem

Comment: Perfect now! Tnx again.